# JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build a react-native app on my mobile phone.
I do have environment path set in my environment variable
[image]

I have my phone in debugging mode with adb devices showing phone connected. 
My java path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2

I get the below error on react-native run-android
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: You should better use JDK v8

Comment: Did you restart your shell after setting JAVA_HOME?

Comment: try to add JAVA_HOME in System Variables not User Variables

Comment: @Robert Yes my problem got solved by using Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name to

```
PATH
```

instead of

```
JAVA_HOME
```

And you  are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding JAVA_HOME as a user variable. You need to add a new variable as JAVA_HOME under system variable and add JDK Path as variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime windows path is broken. try add back below value into PATH with JAVA_HOME will make it work.

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

[image: Sample image how to do it]